# Getting error while logging in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Everything was working yesterday but now i get this

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
```

I have this code

```
secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
```

this routing

```
xxxxxxxx:
    resource: "@myBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation


xxxxxxxx:
    resource: "@myBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /secured
```

DO i need to do any more setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have in your routing

```
_security_check:
    pattern: /login_check
```

And also check, if this route is not overridden by any other

**EDIT**:

You have to place your check_path behind the firewall. Means:

```
check_path:  /admin/login_check
```

Comment: i didn't have that before as well  and everything was working. do i need that route